# Color change not working for InputBase#s placeholder component in react.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have been trying to change the color of inputbase's placeholder. I found few methods online and tried to apply them but none of them are working. Beloware my codes.

```
<InputBase
        id="input-id"
        placeholder="enter the search word"
        className="input"
      />
```

my css:

```
.input::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove inverted commas in  `color: 'blue';`

```
.input::placeholder { 
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: sorry, It is a typing error. I checked all possible ways. But it is still not working.

Comment: did you import css file on react?

Comment: yes, I did, when I try to change the properties of input class it is working but for placeholder it is not working.

Comment: try `.input::placeholder { 
  color: blue!important;
}`

Comment: Yeah, i tried it and even applied createTheme , but it still the same. I could not find out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `!important` flag

```css
.input::placeholder {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

If that doesn't work, make sure that your CSS is imported correctly.

Comment: It is still not working, I confirm the css import by changing the input color it is working. But changing input's placeholder color is not working.